# Unresolved reference: jvmName

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am trying to build a kotlin file with gradle in terminal.

I am getting this error:

```
 Unresolved reference: jvmName
```

Here is a copy of the line from the code:

```
val outputContract = IOUContract::class.jvmName
```

Syntax seems fines. Would appreciate it if someone could give pointers on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following line: `import kotlin.reflect.jvm.jvmName`.

Answer (score 3):

[`KClass<*>.jvmName`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-name.html) belongs to the `kotlin-reflect` library, you probably don't have it included as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where do I add the dependency? In the gradle file?

Comment: Here are kotlin dependencies in my gradle file: ` kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }`

Comment: They seem to point to the reflection library (please correct me if im wrong)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies See the note about reflection.

Comment: Thanks . Added `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"` and its throwing the same error